# AdMob test ads not working on released version of Android app

Tags: android, testing, admob, ads

I have an issue with AdMob in my Android apps.
I added my device id as test device id and test ads are working well in my apps inside the debug version but when I create signed release APK and upload it to the Google play and install my app from Google play I noticed that the test ads have been replaced with live ads.There is no test ad label at the top of the ad.
So anybody know the reason of this issue and how to fix it?
Thanks & Best Regards

Comment: I'm facing the exact same problem with my app. Test ads when installed directly on my device from Android Studio, but real ads when installed through Google Play with a signed release apk. Did you get any feedback on this question or find out what could be the reason?